# C - cannot convert 'void *' to 'bTree' an object

Tags: c, malloc, b-tree

I have a code that create a free BTree but I have an error in line 6 that said `cannot convert void to object` how can I fix it?

```
bTree btCreate(void)
{
bTree b;


b = malloc(sizeof(*b)); // '=':cannot convert 'void *' to 'bTree' 
assert(b);

b->isLeaf = 1;
b->numKeys = 0;

return b;

}
```

any idea?
thanks.

Comment: And *what is* `bTree`?

Comment: So `bTree` is a typedef for a pointer? Please don't do this. This is among the worst uses of a typedef in existence. Pointer semantics need to be explicit. You yourself are already stumbling over it.

Comment: Use C compiler instead of C++ compiler.

Comment: ... or `b = (bTree)malloc(sizeof(*b));`. All other comments still apply.

Answer (score 3):

assuming that bTree is declared as :

```
typedef struct
{
 int isLeaf;
 int numKeys;
}bTree;
```

This is an example of call for your function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
  int isLeaf;
  int numKeys;
}bTree;

bTree* btCreate(void)
{
  bTree *b;

  b = malloc(sizeof(bTree)); //pay attention here sizeof(bTree) 
  if (b==NULL)
  {
    printf ("malloc failed \n");
    return NULL;
  }
  //initialization
  b->isLeaf = 1;
  b->numKeys = 0;

 return b;
}

int main()
{
   bTree* ptree;
   ptree = btCreate();

   if(ptree!=NULL){
     printf ("initial values:\n");
     printf ("isLeaf = %d  \n",ptree->isLeaf);
     printf ("numKeys = %d  \n",ptree->numKeys);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Hope this help